# Why do so many people say "equals to" in maths?

Tags: pronunciation, slang, colloquial-language

It seems to be common to hear `x = 3 sin(α)` pronounced as

> x **equals to** three sine alpha

I would read `x = 3 sin(α)` as "x equals three ...", and I believe this to be the correct pronunciation and hear it more commonly among mathematicians in formal settings and among well-read English-first-language speakers.

So what's origin of the "equals to" (mis?) pronunciation? How did it come to be so pervasive?

Comment: What is your evidence that this is common? I don't remember ever hearing it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a common and correct way of reading *x* = 3 sin(*α*)

> x is equal to three sine alpha.

The use of "equal" as a verb to say "x equals..." is relatively modern. The word "equal" is still mostly used as an adjective except in mathematical contexts.

Given that a common colocation is "equal to", it is unsurprising that some people might treat the verb form as intransitive and say "x equals to ..."  It is fairly harmless.

Comment: 2 x 10 is equal to 10 + 10. But 2 x 10 equals 20.

Comment: Yes, 2 × 10 equals 10 + 10, and 2 × 10 is equal to 20. The two ways of expressing are really quite synonymous.

Comment: Oh interesting. Do you know when the verb `equals` started becoming common then?

Answer (score 2):

In our language (Japanese), as Juhaz says at the comment line, there is no verb which is **directly** equivalent with the verb "equal".

For example, in your case, x=3 sin(α), we take as, (SOV case)

Xはsin(α）の3倍と等しい。

Here, 等しいis equal with English verb "equal", plus we need to insert a particle "と" in order for the sentence to make sense.

So naturally or not, we as learners may be intuitively thinking some particle, in English case, **to**, is needed to complete the sentence, again as Juhasz says.

But definitely in English it is **"wrong".**

Comment: This feels like a japanese SE answer...

Comment: @theonlygusti But you are saying "I hear a significant number of English-second-language speakers,", naturally the answer from the perspective of my own language could come. ( or other language speakers' )

Comment: @theonlygusti I think this is a fair answer to the question. Kentaro is simply using a concrete example from a non-English language to demonstrate the point. However, I'm kind of thinking there's a problem with the question. I'm not entirely sure we should be answering, "why is this mistake common?", or "what is the origin of this mistake?" Doesn't seem quite on-topic to me. Generally, addressing why something is wrong and giving the proper usage is more on-topic, not speculation about the origin.

Comment: @Em. did you delete all the topics on the OP? Some of them were p interesting...

Comment: @theonlygusti Do you mean comments? No, I did not delete them, but if there was an important point in there, the users can preserve them by posting an answer.